# Google-spreadsheets automatically cancels the code's indentation, how to recover?

Tags: google-sheets

I use google-spreadsheets,I want to copy python code to google-spreadsheets,but I find google-spreadsheets automatically cancels the code's indentation.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

rs = pd.read_csv(r'D:/Clustering_TOP.csv',encoding='utf-8')
with open('D:/Clustering_TOP.csv','r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rows = [row for row in reader]
csv_title = rows[0]
csv_title = csv_title[1:]
len_csv_title = len(csv_title)
for i in range(len_csv_title):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(str(csv_title[j])+'_'+str(csv_title[i]) + " = " + str(rs[csv_title[i]].corr(rs[csv_title[j]])), end='\t')
    print()
```

When I paste the code to google-docs,the code turns into this:

[image]

And there is no indentation in the paste option. 
[image]

How can I keep the indentation of the code?

Comment: A spreadsheet seems like a terrible place to put your Python. Why are you doing this?

Comment: I need to make python tutorials for others.

Comment: A spreadsheet seems like a terrible place to put your Python tutorials, too.

Comment: Yes,I think so.But my leader asked me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this workaround? In your title, we can see `how to recover?`. Do you want to add the indentation to the script without indentation which had already been pasted? Or when you paste the script, do you want to keep the indentation? If in the case of later, I think that there are 2 patterns. If the situation is the later, please choose one of 2 patterns. I think that there are several workarounds. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Pattern 1

- Paste the script with line by line.

#### Pattern 2

- Paste the script in the cell "A1".
- Paste this formula in the cell "A2".

  - `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, char(10)))`
  - You can retrieve only the script with the indentation by copying values and pasting as values only.

[image]

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you,sir!In fact,just copy python code to 'A1' ,that is OK!